# Database server for SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server, 2019

Can we use sql server 2016 with service pack 2 for SharePoint 2019?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As a short answer,** Yes SharePoint 2019 supports SQL Server 2016 with SP2.

---

As mentioned at [the Hardware and software requirements for SharePoint Server 2019 documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-2019)

The **Minimum** requirements for a database server in a farm
One of the following:

- Microsoft SQL Server 2016 RTM Standard or Enterprise Editions
- Microsoft SQL Server 2017 RTM Standard or Enterprise Editions for Windows

> **Note:** SQL Server products and all future **public updates** are supported through the SQL Server product lifecycle **that means** SQL Server 2016 with SP2 is supported.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use SQL 2016 or 2017. SharePoint always supports subsequent patches to the base supported version of SQL.